# Remove completed tasks from List<Task>

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, task-parallel-library

I am using TPL in .net 4.0 to work with multiple tasks asynchronously.
The following is the code snippet:

```
List<Task> TaskList = new List<Task>();
while (some condition)
{
    var t = Task.Factory.StartNew( () = > doSomething () );
    TaskList.Add(t)
}

//Wait for all tasks to complete
Task.WaitAll(TaskList.toArray());
```

If the while loop runs for a long time, what happens to the size of "TaskList"?
I am concerned that this is going to take up significant memory if the while loop runs for a couple of days. 
Do I have to remove completed tasks from that list or do they get disposed automatically?

Is there any other way to optimize this in terms of memory?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
TaskList.RemoveAll(x => x.IsCompleted);
```

> Do I have to remove completed tasks from that list or do they get disposed automatically?

no, nobody will remove entries of your `List` if you don't.

Comment: Note: this code sits as a line in your while loop (it was not really specified in the answer)

Comment: @speising: So my concern that the memory impact it will have is correct?

Comment: yes, although i don't know how large a task object is.